upper bound on the volume of the convex hull of point and unit hypercube
Let $\mathcal{U}$ be the unit hypercube in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $C_0 \in \mathbb{R}^n \setminus \mathcal{U}$. Let $\mathcal{K}$ denote the cone
$$
\mathcal{K} = \text{conv}(C_0, \mathcal{U})
$$ Can we upperbound the volume of $\mathcal{K}$? Something like
$$
\text{vol}(\mathcal{K}) \leq \|C_0 - 1_n\| \cdot \text{vol}(\mathcal{U}) ? 
$$

According to this paper "CUBE SLICING IN $R^n$" KEITH BALL the largest area of the intersection of the unit hyperbube $\mathcal{U}$ with a hyper-plane is $\sqrt{2}$.
Consider the hyperplane
$$
\mathcal{H} = \left\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n | \left( C_0 - \frac{1}{2}\cdot 1_{n\times 1}\right)^T \cdot \left( x - \frac{1}{2}\cdot 1_{n\times 1} \right) = 0 \right\}
$$ Since the area of $\mathcal{H} \cap \mathcal{U} \leq \sqrt{2}$, it follows that
$$
\text{vol}(K) \leq \text{vol}(\mathcal{U}) + \left\| C_0 - \frac{1}{2}\cdot 1_{n \times 1}\right\| \cdot \sqrt{2} \leq 1 + \left\| C_0 - \frac{1}{2}\cdot 1_{n \times 1}\right\| \cdot \sqrt{2}
$$
